# "Numpy not Available" After installing Pytorch XLA

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, kaggle

I am just getting started with using TPUs on kaggle with Pytorch and install it as follows -

```
!pip3 install mkl

!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/xla/master/contrib/scripts/env-setup.py -o pytorch-xla-env-setup.py

!python3 pytorch-xla-env-setup.py --version nightly --apt-packages libomp5 libopenblas-dev
```

However, after installing Pytorch XLA, I am not able to use NumPy at all. Whenever I call functions like `np.uint8` or even NumPy based functions from like `torch.from_numpy` I get an error whose bottom line says - `NumPy not Available`. Please note that I am able to import Numpy.
The whole stack trace is as follows -

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-abfcbbc939b0> in <module>
   1026                                  segmentation_Maps='/kaggle/input/pascal-voc/VOC2012/SegmentationClass/') 
   1027 dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=5)
-> 1028 for _, data in enumerate(dataloader):
   1029     i = data['image']
   1030     gt = data['ground_truth']

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    519             if self._sampler_iter is None:
    520                 self._reset()
--> 521             data = self._next_data()
    522             self._num_yielded += 1
    523             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    559     def _next_data(self):
    560         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 561         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    562         if self._pin_memory:
    563             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

<ipython-input-1-abfcbbc939b0> in __getitem__(self, item)
    939         print(mask.shape)
    940         image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image)).convert('RGB')
--> 941         mask = torch.from_numpy(np.uint8(mask))
    942 
    943         image = self.transforms(image)

RuntimeError: Numpy is not available
```

I have no clue what is going on. Could someone please Help. 
PS - please note that pytorch xla updates pytorch to a nightly 1.9 version.  
TIA

Answer (score 4):

At least in Google Colab I was able to solve this issue by running (after installing `xla`):

```
!pip install -U numpy
```

Not completely sure it will help in any context

Comment: The above step is expected to resolve the issue mentioned above. (xla team)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the version mismatch. Currently the **pytorch version 1.12.1+cu113** is compatible with *numpy* version **1.21.6**.

I don't know why this occurs. But keep checking the version in google colab and you can possibly make torch work locally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).